# What are small plywood blocks between flooring and drywall edge?

Tags: drywall, flooring

I'm removing carpet and baseboard to install wood flooring. There's a space between the bottom edge of the drywall and the flooring. I'd like to use that space for the expansion gap for the wood flooring.

In that space are periodic little blocks of plywood. I'd guesstimate from memory they're about 3/8" to 1/2" square by 1 to 1-1/4" long. They're not fastened to anything. They don't reach up to the drywall. They just lay in the space.

What are those little blocks for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were probably installation supports or spacers for the drywall or the baseboard trim. You can remove them.

Comment: +1 on the baseboard, I have used blocks just like that to keep the base from rolling into the tapered edge of the drywall that the base will cover.

Comment: That would explain why they didn't go up to bottom edge of the drywall. I was guessing either supports for installing the drywall that had shrunk over the forty years since the house was built, which seemed somewhat unlikely for plywood -- or something intended to block travel by pests. Spacing the baseboard out from the tapered edge hadn't occurred to me. Thanks for the explanation from both of you.

Comment: In my experience, baseboard is raised for easier and better carpet installation. It has little to do with the drywall's shape.